# Método para alterar subclasse de CSS (cor do texto de item no choicebox)

Tags: java, css, javafx

Eu tenho um choice-box. No meu choice-box tem uma lista de cores pra serem selecionadas pelo usuário através da interface. Toda vez que o usuário seleciona uma cor, o fundo desse mesmo choice-box fica com a mesma cor que o usuário selecionou. Por padrão, a cor da fonte dos items no choice-box é branca, mas, dentre as opções pro usuário escolher, existe a cor branca... logo, quando ele seleciona "Branco", o fundo do choice-box também fica branco... e como a fonte padrão é branca, vcs já sabem... fica tudo branco, "sem texto".

Aqui como fica:

[image: Cor do background do choice-box e do texto brancos...]

No arquivo da StyleSheet tem, referente ao que falei, o seguinte:

```
.choice-box {
        -fx-background-color: black; 
        -fx-mark-color: #950005;
        -fx-border: 1px;
    }

    .choice-box > .label {
        -fx-text-fill: white;   
    }
```

Aí em cima, como podem ver, a cor da fonte do item da lista do choice-box é setada por padrão como branca na segunda classe do CSS, isso é, na subclasse "label", dentro da ".choice-box".

Quando o cara seleciona um item de cor no menu, a seguinte ação é executada no "OnAction" do choice-box (após fazer toda a verificação da cor blablabla):

```
choiceBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + selectedColor + ";");
```

Até aí tudo bem, o choice-box muda de cor tudo filé, porém eu quero colocar a seguinte condição, pra evitar a fonte branca num fundo claro/branco:

```
if(selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(BRANCO)  || 
   selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(AMARELO) ||
   selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(CINZA)  || 
   selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(PRATA)) 
{
    //ação para fazer a cor da fonte do item selecionado no menu ser preta quando a cor selecionada pelo usuário for branca, amarela, cinza ou prata

}
```

Mas eu não estou conseguindo acessar, pelo java, essa subclasse ".label" que fica dentro do choice-box. E não dá pra criar um `@FXML Label meuLabel` referenciando a esse texto. Daria pra fazer isso se o que eu quisesse alterar fosse o Label que fica acima de cada menu, dizendo o que ele é. A ideia seria fazer algo tipo:

```
meuCoiceBox.getValue().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
```

ou um

```
meuChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
```

...pra alterar a cor do texto esse item com fundo claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu caso ficar usando setStyle tem duas desvantagens:

1. É mais difícil de manter em caso de mudanças;
2. Haverá repetição de código desnecessária.

Vou colocar aqui uma solução usando CSS externo, (***se já fez isso pule essa parte***) primeiro você cria um arquivo styles.css em um package no seu projeto (no caso abaixo a default) e adiciona essa linha na sua classe principal:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("styles.css").toString());
```

No arquivo styles.css fiz o seguinte:

```css
.root{ display: block;}
.corBranca{ -fx-background-color: white;}
.corAmarela{-fx-background-color: yellow;}

.corVermelha{-fx-background-color: red;}
.corVermelha .label{ -fx-text-fill: white;}
.corVermelha .context-menu .label{-fx-text-fill: black;}

.corVerde{-fx-background-color: green;}
.corVerde .context-menu .label{-fx-text-fill: black;}
.corVerde .label{ -fx-text-fill: white;}
```

Tive que mudar a cor do context menu para preto onde a letra padrão é branca (você mudou o text-fill de todo o component para branco)

Eis o código java para mudança da cor:

```
ChoiceBox<String> choice = new ChoiceBox();
ObservableList<String> choices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
choices.addAll("corAmarela","corBranca", "corVermelha", "corVerde");
choice.setItems(choices);

choice.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) -> {
    choice.getStyleClass().setAll(t1);
});
```

Eu coloquei o nome dos itens do choicebox igual ao css pra não ter que fazer if-else mas não é obrigatório. O método getStyleClass() diz qual é a classe do componente, funciona como no css normal quando fazemos class="suaClasse".

O resultado é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só mais uma dica: prefira usar os códigos HEX das cores ao invés dos atalhos (white, red, etc) coloquei-os só por questões didáticas.

Comment: Desculpa a demora pra dar um feedback. Ainda não consegui fazer funcionar... devo estar fazendo algo errado. Assim que eu conseguir eu aviso. Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Acho que está conflitando com os "fx:Id" que eu setei pra cada menu desse. Eu consigo setar um id pro css e outro pro fx ?

Comment: Você não me disse que estava usando FXML, estou alterando para adequar a resposta.

Comment: Na verdade, eu consegui fazer funcionar em partes... Ele só funciona corretamente na 1a vez que escolho uma cor do menu. Toda vez que se altera a cor do menu, o onAction do menu chama um método que muda a cor de um retângulo (que fica sobre uma imagem de um resistor). Porém, esse método recebe um parâmetro do tipo choicebox, e salva o nome do Id do menu antes de ir para um switch-case no qual "pergunta" o nome do menu interagido e da cor selecionada e altera a cor do retângulo. Após eu interagir a primeira vez, o menu ganha outro id (para mudar o id do css) e o retangulo para de mudar de cor..

Comment: Eu editei tirando o conflito de Ids, olhe o código e o css novamente.

Comment: Coloquei abaixo minha solução final. Acabei mudando algumas coisas, porém o principal foi ter aprendido o uso desse método "setStyleClass()". Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Precisei responder à minha própria pergunta ao invés de comentar na resposta acima, pois queria mostrar minha solução final, que ficou grande demais pra colocar num comentário lá...

**SOLUÇÃO:**

Quando o usuário seleciona uma cor no choice-box, é chamado um método onde eu salvo a cor numa variável chamada "selectedColor" e , após um switch-case pra mudar a cor do retângulo e alterar o valor da resistência **(até aqui nada diferente do que já estava)**, coloquei o seguinte if-else:

```
if(selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(BRANCO) || selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(AMARELO) || 
       selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(CINZA) || selectedColor.equalsIgnoreCase(PRATA)) {
  choiceBox.getStyleClass().setAll("choice-box","itemCorClara");
} else {
  choiceBox.getStyleClass().setAll("choice-box","itemCorEscura");
}
```

Não usei o addListener, pois não achei necessário. Não sei nem se do meu jeito ficou mais "feio" ou fora de padrão, mas achei mais fácil de eu entender o que eu fiz ali.

Quando eu seto a classe de acordo com a cor, aí nesse if-else, eu, na verdade, setei 2 classes pro Choice-Box, sendo uma "classe base" (choice-box) e uma com a "customização" que eu queria (itemCorClara ou itemCorEscura), ficando meu arquivo do CSS assim:

```
.choice-box {
    -fx-background-color: black; 
    -fx-mark-color: #950005;
}

.choice-box .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;   
}

.choice-box .context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: #666666;    
}

.choice-box .menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background-color: #950005;   
}

.choice-box .menu-item > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: black;   
}

.choice-box .menu-item:focused > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;   
}

/*#####################################*/

.itemCorEscura .label {
    -fx-text-fill: white;   /
}

/*######################################*/

.itemCorClara .label {
    -fx-text-fill: #000000;   
}
```

E, continuei usando o setStyle pra alterar somente o background do choice-box, pois achei melhor do que criar uma classe pra cada cor. Minha dúvida é só se realmente fica melhor com o setStyle ou se criando uma classe pra cada cor mesmo. Ou é só questão de gosto pessoal?

```
choiceBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + traduzirCor(choiceBox.getValue()) + "; -fx-mark-color: #950005;");
```

Esse método "traduzirCor(choiceBox.getValue())" que usei é só um que fiz pra me devolver um nome de cor "entendível" pelo css, já que o valor recebido do choice-box é o nome da cor em português (Ex.: "BRANCO").

Só assim eu realmente consegui deixar tudo 100%, até então sempre tinha alguma coisinha dando errado.

Obrigado pela ENORME ajuda, Gustavo, aprendi bastante de ontem pra hoje! Todas as observações anotadas!